# How to use PostgreSQL xmlexists() function in Hibernate HQL query?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I want to create HQL query with `xmlexists()` function but I get an error.

My code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("From XMLTable AS tb WHERE xmlexists('//food[@id = \"1\"]' PASSING BY REF tb.xmlData)");

List list = query.list();

list.forEach(obj -> {
        printSth((XMLTable) obj);
});
```

ERROR:

> ERROR: line 1:77: unexpected token: PASSING

I also tried in pgAdmin 4 and there everything works fine. I guess that this is a syntax problem in HQL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the unorthodox syntax of the function you use.

An obvious solution for the problem would be to use `session.createNativeQuery()` instead of a JPQL query. You can then (and should) use plain SQL as the method argument.

Another solution might be to extend the dialect class Hibernate provides for PostgreSQL and register a new function implementation for `xmlexists()`. I am not sure if that would work though.